# LINQ equals - what does it call under the covers?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-3.5

I read in a few places that LINQ equals (in join syntax) calls IEquatable for the type it's comparing, but I don't see it happening in my join:

```
List<ILData> list1 = new List<ILData> { /* Initialized with items */ };
List<ILData> list2 = new List<ILData> { /* Initialized with items */ };

var joinItems = (
    from d1 in list1
        join d2 in list2
        on d1 equals d2
    where d1.SomeValue == "7"
    select d1).Distinct().ToList<ILData>();
```

Assuming I provided an interface definition satisfying:

```
ILData : IEquatable<ILData>
```

requirements, why wouldn't I be seeing ILData::Equals get called in this case?

Comment: What type are `list1` and `list2`?

Comment: you could refer to here, it get called when equality methods are fired.
[When To Use IEquatable And Why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476793/when-to-use-iequatable-and-why)

Comment: @Jordrell : clarified hte code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`. Since your type implements `IEquatable<T>`, the actual comparer used will be an internal class called  `System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer<T>`, which will delegate `GetHashCode` and `Equals` requests to your `object.GetHashCode`method and `IEquatable<ILData>.Equals` methods respectively (except for `null` references, where it returns a zero hash-code / does a reference-equality check without calling your methods).

There are a number of reasons that could explain your `Equals` method not being hit:

1. There's an empty sequence at play here.
2. Your breakpoint is on `object.Equals` rather than `IEquatable<ILData>.Equals`
3. The second sequence only contains `null` references (this is checked by the framework comparer, so it won't enter yours).
4. There are no hash matches (from `GetHashCode`), so the join operation never needs to do a full equality check. One reason this might be happening is that you forgot to override this method and are therefore stuck with the default one from `object` (which is designed for reference equality and will be inconsistent with your definition of equality).

Comment: My comparison logic is complicated enough that I can't represent any of it with a GetHashCode result, so I made GetHashCode return a constant so Equals() gets called every time.  So, #4 was the ticket :)

Answer (score 0):

The [Join function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx) says it uses the [default equality comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx). You need to override object.GetHashCode (and should override object.Equals) in addition to implementing IEquatable.

In general, the query

```
from AA in AAAA
join BB in BBBB
on C(AA) equals D(BB)
select E(AA,BB)
```

translates to

```
AAAA.Join(BBBB, AA => C(AA), BB => D(BB), (AA, BB) => E(AA, BB))
```